# What is the function of “而” and “使” in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage, meaning-in-context

all.

I'm reading through a textbook and came across this sentence:

“那些得益于畜牧农耕而使人类实现了定居的地方，大都成为人类文明的摇篮。”

Overall, the sentence doesn't really give me much trouble except for that “而使” in the first clause there. What are the functions of these two characters here? My first thought was that the "而" here is being used as part of a cause and effect structure, but that doesn't seem quite right to me, and I still don't know what the "使" is all about. Usually when I see that character it means "make," but I don't know about that in this case. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**那些地方** = **those places**

**那些** [(因)得益于畜牧农耕(而)使人类实现了定居的] **地方** = **Those places** [that (because of) benefited from cattle raising and farming (therefore), make humans become permanent residence possible]

(**因**) 得益于畜牧农耕 (**而**) 使人类实现了定居的 = (**because of**)...(**therefore**)......

因 in "因 A 而 B" is omitted.

A is "得益于畜牧农耕"

B is "使人类实现了定居"

的 turns this entire phrase into an adjectival phrase for 地方